# How to prove this $a(a-1)^2+b(b-1)^2\ge (a-1)^2(b-1)^2(a+b-1),a,b\ge 0$

Tags: inequality

Assmue that $a,b\ge 0$,show that

$$a(a-1)^2+b(b-1)^2\ge (a-1)(b-1)(a+b-1)$$

Comment: Does not look right, fails when $a=b=1000$.

Comment: Set $a=b = 11$. Then the inequality does not hold

Comment: sorr,I have edit it.

Comment: @Mher,$LHS=\dfrac{1}{8}$,and $RHS<0$

Comment: If you make it homogenous with $c=1$, the inequality becomes $a^3+b^3+c^3+3abc\geq a^2b+ab^2+a^2c+ac^2+b^2c+bc^2$, which is nice and symmetric.

Comment: oh, it's schur inequality!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let $a+b=x,ab=y$  then

$a(a-1)^2+b(b-1)^2\ge (a-1)(b-1)(a+b-1) \Leftrightarrow$

$(x-1)^2 (x+1)+y(5-4x)\ge 0$

if $5 \ge 4x$ then inequality is obvious with equality at $y=0,x=1$

if $5<4x$ then from AmGm inequality we have $y\le \dfrac {x^2} 4$ so

$(x-1)^2 (x+1)+y(5-4x)\ge (x-1)^2(x+1)+\dfrac {x^2 (5-4x)} 4=\dfrac {(x-2)^2} 2 \ge 0$

equality holds if $x=2,y=1$

the inequality is equivalent with

$a^3+b^3+1+3ab\ge ab(a+b)+a(a+1)+b(b+1)$

which is thirth degree Schur inequality

Comment: It's Nice answer! Thank you +1