# Why this polynomial can't be expressed as a sum of squares of some polynomials (the real coefficients)

Tags: polynomials, contest-math

Before we has prove this polynomials is postive [semi-definite](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1396821/how-to-prove-this-aa-12bb-12-ge-a-12b-12ab-1-a-b-ge-0),Now I want to show that this postive semi-definite polynomials 
$$x^2(x^2-1)^2+y^2(y^2-1)^2+(x^2-1)(y^2-1)(x^2+y^2-1)$$  can't be expressed as a sum of squares of some polynomials (the real coefficients)

Comment: what contest would that be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consider $$f(x,y)=p_1(x,y)^2+p_2(x,y)^2+...+p_3(x,y)^2$$ then if $f(x,y)=0$.
 we have $p_1(x,y)=0$. $q(y)=f(0,y)$ has three distinct root( y=0,1,-1). so we have $p_1(0,y)$ has three root so we have $p_1(0,y)=c_1 y(y^2-1)$. in the similar way we have $p_1(x,0)=c_2 x(x^2-1)$ so we have $$p_1(x,y)=c_1 x(x^2-1)+c_2 y(y^2-1)+c_3  xy+c_4 x^2y+c_5xy^2$$
$$f(1,1)=0\to p(1,1)=0\to c_3+c_4+c_5=0$$
$$f(1,-1)=0\to p(1,-1)=0\to c_3+c_4-c_5=0$$
$$f(-1,1)=0\to p(-1,1)=0\to c_3-c_4+c_5=0$$
so we have $c_3=c_4=c_5=0$:
$$\forall i  p_i(x,y)=c_{1_i}x(x^2-1)+c_{2,i}y(y^2-1)\to$$
$$f(x,y)=\sum c_{1_i}^2x(x^2-1)+\sum c_{2,i}^2y(y^2-1)+2\sum c_{1_i}x(x^2-1)c_{2,i}y(y^2-1)$$
but clearly this is impossible