# Let $a^n = a^{n - 1} + a^{n -2}$. Show that for any $A, B$, $F(n) = Aa^n + Bb^n$ satisfies Fibonacci recurrence relation.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fibonacci-numbers

$$\begin{align*}
F(n) &= Aa^n + Bb^n\\
&= A(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}) + B(b^{n-1}+b^{n-2}) \\
&= Aa^{n -1} + Aa^{n-2} + Bb^{n -1} + Bb^{n-2}\\
&= a^{n -1} (A + A^{a-1}) + b^{n - 2} (B + bB)
\end{align*}$$

Use $$ \color{red}{ a > 1; \; \; b = \frac{-1}{a}.}   $$

Would that work?

edit: Suppose recurrence relation given by $F(n) = F(n - 1) + F(n - 2)$ grows at the same rate as some function $a^n$. Then, $a^n = a^{n -1} + a^{n -2}$ by substitution. $a^n \to a^2 = a + 1$. One of its roots is negative and we call it $b$. Since $a^n, b^n$ satisfy Fibonacci recurrence relation, $F(n) = Aa^n + Bb^n$ also does. That's what I want to prove.

Comment: What is $b$? The problem doesn't say. Without that, the claim is false, for if $A = 0$ and $B = b = 1$, then $F$ does not have the Fibonacci property.Your "proof" is also wrong (for the same reason): you've assumed that $b^n = b^{n-1} + b^{n-2}$, which was not given, and for most values of $b$, it's not true. (Example: $b = 1$.) The last equality is also wrong --- some serious algebra errors. You probably wanted to say that it's $(A a^{n-1} + B b^{n-1}) + (A a^{n-2} + B b^{n-2})$, by rearranging terms, and that this is just $F(n-1) + F(n-2)$.

Comment: $a^n$ simplifies down to $a^2 = a + 1$. One of $a^2$'s roots is negative and we call it $b$.

Comment: Perhaps you should edit the claim then, since as stated, it's false.

Comment: Also: the two roots of $a^2$ are $a$ and $-a$, but the second one does not have the Fibo property. It's the second root of the equation $a^2 - a - 1 = 0$ that has that property. I'm being precise here because you asked a precalc question, and one of the tough parts of precalc is learning how much precision in language matters as you advance in mathematics (and, of course, how to be precise yourself).

Comment: I just edited my OP.

Comment: Dear @JohnHughes, do you know how to write a non-negative polynomial (two variables) as the sum of squares of rational functions, as in Hilbert's 17th problem? There does seem to be a fair amount of literature on computer algorithms. I refer to this recent http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1397235/why-this-polynomial-cant-be-expressed-as-a-sum-of-squares-of-some-polynomials

Comment: No clue...but is this relevant to the current question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try rewriting the question *and* giving an answer:

**Restated question**
Suppose that $a$ and $b$ are the two solutions to $x^2 - x - 1 = 0$, so that we have $a^2 = a + 1$ (and similarly for $b$) and hence also 
\begin{align}
a^n &= a^{n-1} + a^{n-2}& \text{ (**) }
\end{align}
for $n \ge 2$, and similarly for $b$.

Show that for any $A, B$, the function 
$$
F(n) = A a^n + B b^n
$$
has the Fibonacci property, i.e., that
$$
F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2)
$$
for all integers $n \ge 2$.

**Solution to this rephrased problem**
Suppose $n$ is any integer greater than 2. Then 
\begin{align}
F(n) 
&= Aa^n + B b^n & \text{ by definition of $F$}\\
&= A(a^{n-1} + a^{n-2}) + B (b^{n-1} + b^{n-2}) & \text{ by equation (**) }\\
&= A a^{n-1} + A a^{n-2} + Bb^{n-1} + B b^{n-2} & \text{ by distributive law, twice }\\
&= A a^{n-1} + B b^{n-1} + A a^{n-2} + B b^{n-2} & \text{ by commutative lawfor addition }\\
&= \left( A a^{n-1} + B b^{n-1} \right) + \left( A a^{n-2} + B b^{n-2} \right )& \text{parens added for clarity }\\
&= F(n-1)+ F(n-2) & \text{definition of $F$, twice }.
\end{align}

The second and last steps are justified because we have $n \ge 2$, in case you were wondering about that bit. So we've shown that $F$ satisfies the Fibonacci recurrence for all $n \ge 2$, as required.

Comment: I was wondering about the step next to last. I didn't know we could allow two terms inside parenthesis like $(Aa^{n -1} + Bb^{n -1})$. I thought we'd have to derive something like $(Ax + By)^{n -1}$ instead. Thanks.